# JS - Ignore numbers after decimal point

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

So I am trying to convert the `.text()` of a div into a number that can be used for some math within the JS (currency conversion). I am gathering the text content of a div which contains items such as currency symbols as well as a decimal point which is always followed by 00 
For example if the div contained `£35,000.00` I am trying to get it to return `35000` not `3500000`.

I have got some RegExp that only allows use of numbers 1-9 and therefore removes the £ sign but it also takes the decimal point out, thus multiplying the number I want by 100.

This is my code:

```
var thisDiv = $(this);
var amount = $( this ).text().replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');
```

Is there any way to ignore the numbers that come after the dot other than just dividing my variable by 100?

Comment: If your values *always* end in ".00" wouldn't it be easier to either truncate the purely numeric values or adjust your math by a factor of 100?

Comment: I think I am just going to divide the var by 100 - seems the easiest way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/[^0-9\.]/
```

this regex will keep 0-9 and .

However, it will also allow values like 1.2.3 (multiple dots)

if you want more validation than that, you might want to take a couple steps

```
var numberString = value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/gi, '');
if (isNaN(numberString )) {
   console.log('invalid');
} else {
   //parse number and use it
}
```

Comment: The `.` inside a character class does not have to be escaped, and there is no point adding the `/i` modifier since digits and a dot do not have lower and upper case variants.

Comment: Meh, valid points, but in the end those extra characters don't break anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict what you match with `[^0-9]` using a `(?!\.\d+$)` negative lookahead:

```
/(?!\.\d+$)[^0-9]/g
 ^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zM7mQ8/2)

The pattern means: match any non-digit if it is not a literal `.` followed with 1+ digit up to the end of the string.

```js
var re = /(?!\.\d+$)[^0-9]/g; 
var str = '£35,000.00';
var result = str.replace(re, '');
document.body.innerHTML = result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending on Mark's answer, you can the digits number before and after the decimal with the following:

```
numberString.toString().split(".")[0];   //before
numberString.toString().split(".")[1];   //after
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to convert to string and split and get the 0 index just do
`.toFixed();`
Like:

```
const num = 34.434343;
num.toFixed();
```